# How to get value from Multiple Checkbox to array in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to get multiple checkbox values to an array in react js? This is my dynamic destination places from API. I want post to Backend with an array.

```
{
  this.state.destination.length > 0 ? (
    this.state.destination.map((destination, index) => (
      <div className="col-md-3">
        <div class="pretty p-default">
          <input type="checkbox" name="dest" value={index} onClick={event => this.handleDestination(event)} />
          <div class="state p-primary">
            <label>{destination.dest_name}</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))
  ) : (
    <div>
      <label>
        <b>No results found ! </b>{' '}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}



handleDestination(event) {

    const options=this.state.options
    let index
    if(event.target.checked){
      options.push(+event.target.value)
    }
    else{
      index=options.indexOf(+event.target.value)
      options.splice(index,1)
    }
    this.setState({ options:options})

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/ziad-saab/react-checkbox-group ?

Answer (score 4):

You can bind your `handleDestination` method with with an extra parameter - index of checked element:
`this.handleDestination.bind(this, index)`

Worked example [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/97207/):

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  ...      
  onToggle(index, e){
    let newItems = this.state.items.slice();
    newItems[index].checked = !newItems[index].checked

    this.setState({ items: newItems })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <ul>
          {this.state.items.map((item, i) =>
            <li key={i}>
              {item.text}
              // binding an index
              <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.onToggle.bind(this, i)} />
            </li>
          )}
          </ul>
        <br/>
          // filter by checked element
          You checked: {JSON.stringify(this.state.items.filter(item => item.checked))}
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
For your code - change

```
this.handleDestination(event)
```

to

```
this.handleDestination.bind(this, index)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then modify a `handleDestination` method to similar what i did above:

```
handleDestination(index, event){
  console.log(index) // checked element index
  console.log(this.props.destination[index]) // your checked element
  ...
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: I gotcha my new function is like that .It works well. but the value is not coming out, the index of array is coming .How can I change .this is my new function

Comment: I updated my question again .Let me check above my handleDestination function.I do not want to get index of array, I want value . HOw can I fix that

Comment: @GuGue Have you looked at my worked example? I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar pattern that i used in my project.You can reference here.

```
 state = {
    form: {
      companyType: '',
      services: [],
      name: '',
      surname: '',
      email: '',
      concepts: [],
      technologies: [],
    },
  };


public handleChange = (event: any) => {
    const { name } = event.target;
    const checkedArr = [];
    let value;
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
      value = event.target.value;
    } else {
      const checkeds = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
      for (let i = 0; i < checkeds.length; i++) {
        if (checkeds[i].checked) {
          checkedArr.push(checkeds[i].value);
        }
      }
      value = checkedArr;
    }

    const { form } = this.state;
    form[name] = value;

    this.setState({ form });
  };
```

I'm getting checkbox values into  arrays.